# jsTree jQuery: select_node error: "Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined" when I clicked a jsTree node on my website.

Upon node click, the jsTree should use a key to retrieve a value, save it to a form, and submit the form. This is how "attr" in my JSON is defined:

`"attr":{"href":"/animal/mammal/dog"}`

This is how the node is bound:

```
$("#divCategoryTree")
  .jstree(config_obj)
  .bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    var href = data.rslt.obj.attr("href");
    $("#hdCategoryPath").val(href);
    $("#searchForm").submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have to confess, I am not entirely sure about what `data.rslt.obj.attr` does, but it seems like a standard practice in online examples. I think it goes to the object's `attr` field and uses `href` as the key to retrieve its respective value. If anyone can point me to its documentation, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `href` of clicked node use:

```
data.event.currentTarget.href
```

like here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/8qydnanx/)

Comment: It works! I am so grateful!

Is there a good documentation about jsTree? It might be my own fault, but I could not find documentation about either "rslt.obj.attr(href)" or "event.currentTarget.href" on jsTree.com or its gitHub. Examples there seem simple. In addition, many ways of defining and interacting with jsTree seemed circulating on the web.
Where do you usually get your info about jsTree?

Comment: You are very welcome! The best way is to `console.dir(...)` whatever arguments you have inside the function (jsTree or not) and explore the output in Chrome developer console.

Comment: HI, but does your example retrieve a key-value pair's value from the tsTree JSON?

Comment: It just shows the `href` attribute. Please explain a bit more what functionality you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to jsTree and I might be confused about what problem I encountered.

I thought in order to retrieve some values in jsTree, we must create a field "attr" to store data and for jQuery's attr() function to retrieve it. And '"data.rslt.obj.attr("href")" is how to retrieve a value with key "href".

The "href" I have here is a "key" for me to retrieve its value. Hence I was confused because your code does not have a "href". Your href seems like something existed in jsTree by default.

I think my question might be: How/where to store a data in jsTree and how to retrieve it?

Comment: The old jsTree website is where I get the idea of the model.

[link](https://old.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)

Comment: You can store data in attributes of `li` elements of the tree. You can pass them with all the rest of JSON like this `"li_attr": { "data-key1": "value1", "data-key2": "value2" }`. Check fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/8qydnanx/](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/8qydnanx/). You can also store data in `data` property of any element with jQuery but that is independent of jsTree (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).